# Does a webpage load images slower if there are multiple sources?

Tags: javascript, image, src

Scenario 1: I post pictures on my Facebook profile and create a webpage that has image SRCs linking to the Facebook profile

Scenario 2: I link my SRCs to images from Google searches. This means multiple sources for my images.

Is scenario 1 faster than scenario 2 since it's pulling from one page, or are they the same because each image SRC is a request that takes time to process depending on the source?

Comment: Scenario 2 needs two initial DNS requests to resolve the two different hot names. But that should usually be rather negligible. In cases were it makes a significant difference, a DNS-prefetch could help.

Comment: And of course the remote servers might have limits on how many resources a client can fetch at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max parallel HTTP connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)